# Iteration through a linked list against itself not working as expected

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am very sorry if this has been answered before.

Upon running this code I wish to iterate through a linked list and then iterate through it again for each element in the list. I would love to know what on earth I am doing wrong here. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

node_t * push_end(node_t * end, int data) {
    end->next = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    end->next->data = data;
    end->next->next = NULL;
    return end->next;
}

int main() {

    node_t * head = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    head->data = 0;
    head->next = NULL;

    node_t * end = head;

    end = push_end(end, 1);
    end = push_end(end, 2);

    node_t *i_obj = head;
    node_t *j_obj = head;

    while(i_obj != NULL) {
        while(j_obj != NULL) {
            printf("%d, %d | ", i_obj->data, j_obj->data);
            j_obj = j_obj->next;
        }
        i_obj = i_obj->next;
    }
}
```

Expected output:
`0, 0 | 0, 1 | 0, 2 | 1, 0 | 1, 1 | 1, 2 | 2, 0 | 2, 1 | 2, 2 |`

Actual output:
`0, 0 | 0, 1 | 0, 2 |`

Comment: @jarmod: They want the Cartesian product of the list with itself.

Comment: Your code needs to initialize `j_obj` for each `i_obj` but fails to do so; it initializes `j_obj` only once, before the loops start.

Comment: “I… tried everything to no avail” is not a true statement. Do not exaggerate when describing a problem. To be a good programmer, you must learn to be precise.

Comment: Yeah haha, a bit melodramatic of me, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset `j_obj` to point to the head node for each iteration of `i_obj`. As it stands, `j_obj` becomes NULL at the completion of the first time through the inner loop and stays NULL, so the inner loop is never executed 2nd or 3rd time through.

Change the latter part of your code as follows:

```
node_t *i_obj = head;

while(i_obj != NULL) {
    node_t *j_obj = head;
    while(j_obj != NULL) {
        printf("%d, %d | ", i_obj->data, j_obj->data);
        j_obj = j_obj->next;
    }
    i_obj = i_obj->next;
}
```

Another, arguably clearer, way to write this would be:

```
for (node_t *p = head; p; p = p->next) {
    for (node_t *q = head; q; q = q->next) {
        printf("%d, %d | ", p->data, q->data);
    }
}
```